# Adding an argument to a decorator

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have this decorator, used to decorate a django view when I do not want the view to be executed if the `share` argument is `True` (handled by middleware)

```
class no_share(object):
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Don't let them in if it's shared"""

        if kwargs.get('shared', True):
            from django.http import Http404
            raise Http404('not availiable for sharing')

        return self.view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

It currently works like this:

```
@no_share
def prefs(request, [...])
```

But I'm wanting to expand the functionality a little bit, so that it will work like this:

```
@no_share('prefs')
def prefs(request, [...])
```

My question is how can I modify this decorator class so that it accepts extra arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope [this](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845) article by Bruce Eckel helps.

**Upd:**
According to the article your code will look like this:

```
class no_share(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1

    def __call__(self, f):
        """Don't let them in if it's shared"""

        # Do something with the argument passed to the decorator.
        print 'Decorator arguments:', self.arg1

        def wrapped_f(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if kwargs.get('shared', True):
                from django.http import Http404
                raise Http404('not availiable for sharing')
            f(request, *args, **kwargs)            
        return wrapped_f
```

to be used as desired:

```
@no_share('prefs')
def prefs(request, [...])
```

Answer (score 4):

The Bruce Eckel [article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845) that Li0liQ mentioned should be helpful in figuring this out.  Decorators with and with out arguments behave slightly differently.  The big difference is that when you pass arguments the __call__ method gets called once on __init__ and it is supposed to return a function that will be called whenever the decorated function is called.  When there are no arguments, the __call__ method gets called every time the decorated function is called.

What does this mean for you?  The way that __init__ and __call__ are called for a `@no_arg_decorator` is different than they are called for a `@decorator('with','args')`.

Here are two decorators that might do the trick for you.  You can get away with just the @no_share_on(...) decorator as long as you always use it with the parentheses.

```
def sharing_check(view, attr_name, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get(attr_name, True):
        from django.http import Http404
        raise Http404('not availiable for sharing')

    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

class no_share(object):
    """A decorator w/o arguments.  Usage:
    @no_share
    def f(request):
        ...
    """
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return sharing_check(self.view, 'sharing', request, *args, **kwargs)

class no_share_on(object):
    """A decorator w/ arguments.  Usage:
    @no_share_on('something')
    def f(request):
        ...
    --OR--
    @no_share_on()
    def g(request):
        ...
    """
    def __init__(self, attr_name='sharing'):
        self.attr_name = attr_name

    def  __call__(self, view):
        def wrapper_f(request, *args, **kwargs):
            return sharing_check(view, self.attr_name, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class no_share(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, view):
        self.foo = foo
        self.view = view
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, I tried that already, but I think django works differently or something because that didn't work. I tried to put `print "blah"` in the init, but all I got was a bunch of 'blah's when I started the dev server. No more 'blah's after that...

Comment: That's expected, __init__ is only called once, upon the definition of each view function you decorate with this. The __call__ is called every time your server executes the view function to respond to a request.

This answer is in the right direction, see my answer for a more complete answer specific for your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think closure may works here.

```
def no_share(attr):
    def _no_share(decorated):
        def func(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            """Don't let them in if it's shared"""

            if kwargs.get(attr, True):
                from django.http import Http404
                raise Http404('not availiable for sharing')

            return decorated(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return func
    return _no_share
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you're getting this wrong somewhere, here's a more complete example which may help you see what you're doing wrong. Using this as a drop-in should work.

```
class no_share(object):
    def __init__(self, view, attr_name):
        self.view = view
        self.attr_name = attr_name

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Don't let them in if it's shared"""

        if kwargs.get(self.attr_name, True):
            from django.http import Http404
            raise Http404('not availiable for sharing')

        return self.view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this ia a little late .. but I didn't see any mentions for this way of doing things (probably because it didn't exist when the question was asked), but, in the interests of completeness 
I found it useful to look at how Django themselves implemented such a thing. Have a look at:

django.views.decorators.http.require_http_methods
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/decorators/http.py

```
from functools import wraps
from django.utils.decorators import decorator_from_middleware, available_attrs

def require_http_methods(request_method_list):
    """
    Decorator to make a view only accept particular request methods. Usage::

    @require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
    def my_view(request):
    # I can assume now that only GET or POST requests make it this far
    # ...

    Note that request methods should be in uppercase.
    """
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func, assigned=available_attrs(func))
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            # .. do stuff here

            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return decorator
```